# Value or Function that returns Value as parameter type

Tags: typescript

What is the correct syntax for defining a function parameter type as this:

- `Date` or a function that returns one;
- `Array` or a function that returns one.

I thought I could just write directly:

- `funcName(value:Date|()=>Date)`
- `funcName(value:Array<number>|()=>Array<number>)`

But turns out, such syntax isn't recognized.

How should it be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some parentheses:

```
class X {
    funcName(value: (Array<number>) | (() => Array<number>)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, and I thought that I had enough coffee this morning. I should have thought about it myself. Thank you for your answer!